# IONIC 5 , some css/Scss works fine in browser but doesn't in phone

Tags: android, html, css, sass, ionic5

It seems like the `display:..` is causing the problem (not sure) because every thing works just fine except:

```
display:grid;,

display:content;,

display:bloc;
```

**The page in the browser:**

[image: the page in browser]

**The page in Android:**

[image: the page in android]

Comment: I think you are going to need to add some more information to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you had used ionic default ion tags then it takes some structure from shadow root and it cannot be overridden.